# ReactJs - Inject CSS from root

Tags: css, reactjs

It seems to be a super simple question, but I am today still unable to answer it.

I need, from the root, to do something like `import index.css;` from `main.tsx`. By doing this, I should be able to, from any child of **root**, do something as:

```
<div className="anyStyle" />
```

However, as of now, I am only able to import from a "side css". I do understand that reactjs is mostly designed to have tsx/css per component, but I need something I bit different for a use case :)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import a css file into the parent component and it should apply to each child. You can use a bundler like webpack to read the css import and load it appropriately [load a css file with webpack guide](https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-management/#loading-css)

```
import '../styles.css'

export default function App() {
    return (
        <main></main>
    )
}
```

You can also import the css style in the html directly as well.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>

<div id="root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="react.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Simple webpack config:

```js
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    bundle: './src/app.tsx'
  },
  resolve: {
    // Add '.ts' and '.tsx' as resolvable extensions.
    extensions: ['*', '.ts', '.tsx', '.js']
  },
  module: {
      rules: [
          /*
           * Typsecript files. 
           */
          {
              test: /\.ts(x?)$/,
              exclude: /node_modules/,
              use: [
                  {
                      loader: "ts-loader"
                  }
              ]
          },
          {
            enforce: "pre",
            test: /\.js$/,
            loader: "source-map-loader"
        },
          /*
           * misc Files. 
           */
          {
              test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif|ttf|otf)$/,
              exclude: /node_modules/,
              use: [
                'file-loader'
              ]
          },
           /*
           * CSS Files. 
           */
          {
              test: /\.css$/,
              exclude: /node_modules/,
              use: [
                'style-loader',
                'css-loader',
                "postcss-loader"
            ]
          }
      ]
  },
  plugins: [
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: '[name].js'
  },
};
```

Download with npm:

```
npm i style-loader css-loader postcss-loader
```

Comment: Hey thanks, I do use webpack and currently trying different config but without being able to find the way. Could you precise your webpack configuration content as well as the content of your style.css please? :)

Comment: thanks, what does <main/> stands for? (sorry i am quite a beginner)

Comment: <main> is an html5 tag almost like a <div> or <span>. It is just used to provide more descriptiveness to the html document. The <main> tag specifies the main content of a document and the content inside the <main> element should be unique to the document.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/), which you probably already do, which is included when you base your project upon [create-react-app](https://create-react-app.dev/), which you probably also already do :)

With this you can simply import a css file like you would any other component. Let's say you have a `index.css` with this content:

```css
.anyStyle: {
  margin: 20px;
}
```

In any component you can now do the following:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './index.css';

class Main extends Component {
  render() {
    return <div className="anyStyle" />;
  }
}
```

Edit: Here's a link explaining how to use [css-loader with webpack](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/css-loader/) and how to configure it in your webpack.config, which is already a part of create-react-app afaik.

Comment: Hey :) Thanks, that's what I want to achieve but it doesn't work.. Could you precise your webpack config? Mine is close to https://github.com/Emixam23/react-mobx-typescript-boilerplate/blob/master/webpack.config.js

Comment: @Emixam23 I edited my answer with a link explaining how to install css-loader and how to edit the config, is this what you need?